# How to call correct constructor from an inherited Base.fromFoo() static method

Tags: javascript, inheritance

A `Base` class has multiple class methods which call the class constructor to create new instances of `Base` from various sources.

When I extend `Base` my derived class gets of `Base`'s static methods.

The problem is that the static functions still return instances of `Base`, rather than instances of my derived class.

Is there a way of "adapting" or "genericising" these methods when extending a base class, so that they call the constructor of the derived class instead?

Comment: Can you please share minimal reproducible code?

Comment: If you're not binding `this` value when calling a static method, `new this();` does the trick.